# Build a cheaper highway

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, discrete-optimization

We consider a non-directed graph, where each vertex is a city and each edge is a possible road connecting two cities.

I need to build a cheap highway (a path on a graph) connecting all the cities starting and ending with the main city. I know the cost to build each edge that connects two  verteces (connects two cities). This is the only restriction: to visit all vertices of the graph. The goal is to minimize the cost to build this highway.

This problem is similar to the [Traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but here I can visit each vertex of the graph more than once, and also only the first time that I use an edge I pay to build it, but from the second it has no cost.

I'm not sure if I can connect the Traveling salesman problem with my problem, may be there are other way to solve it. I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Are the weights between cities fixed? Perhaps some algorithmic approach using a minimum spanning tree, e.g. Kruskal's

Comment: Thanks @masiewpao, is what I'm looking for. Ans yes, the weights between cities are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) problem, and a greedy algorithm is optimal.